# Domain for visible/hidden a boolean field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I defined a `boolean` field and two `selection` field.

***.py**

```py
type = fields.Selection([('remove','Remove'),('business_task','Task')])
input = fields.Selection([('1','Yes'),('0','No')])
provide = fields.Boolean('Provide?')
```

I need to invisible `boolean` field if `type != 'remove' or 'type != 'task' and input != 1`

***.xml**

I tried below code, but no luck

```xml
<field name="air_ticket" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('type','!=','remove'),('type','!=','business_task'),('input','!=',1)],'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}"/>
```

**And**

```xml
<field name="air_ticket" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','!=','remove'),'|',('type','!=','business_task'),('input','!=',1)],'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}"/>
```

How can i do this?

**Edit**
As per `Cherif` a i tried below code:

```xml
<field name="air_ticket" attrs="{'invisible':['|',('type','!=','remove'),'&amp;',('type','!=','business_task'),('inside_outside','!=',1)],'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}"/>
```

Now problem is, the field is completely INVISIBLE.

Comment: In "type", you have 2 options and if any of these value set and input not 1 then you want to make field invisible, right?

Comment: If `type == 'remove'` no need to check `input` value. only for `business_task`.

Answer (score 0):

For this domain:

```
       type ! =  'remove' or ('type != 'task' and input != 1)
```

Use this

```
            ['|', ('type', '! =', 'remove), '&',  ('type', '=', 'task'), ('input', '! =', 1)]
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Cherif, But when use `&` in xml fil it gives an error like `XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 232, column 86
`

Comment: There is a special charecter for it i forget how to write it example for >  it's. `&gt;` i'm using my phone just look in odoo code for domain example.

Comment: Now field is completely invisible.

Comment: Your field should be visible when type=remove and the other part of domain is not correct because it's included in type! =reloved describe when you want the field to be visible

Answer (score 0):

Please try as following :

If type= 'business_task' and input is not '1' then make field invisible.

```
attrs="{'invisible':[('type','=','business_task'),('input','!=','1')],'readonly':[('state','!=','draft')]}"
```